# when calculating optical flow, why frame has no value?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

so I'm trying to implement this code for optical flow
but when I try to call cv2.imshow('frame',img) I get an error because img, frame, and mask are all "None".

can anybody help me understand where the problem is?

here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                   qualityLevel = 0.3,
                   minDistance = 7,
                   blockSize = 7 )


lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
              maxLevel = 2,
              criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))


color = np.random.randint(0,255,(100,3))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while( cap.isOpened() ) :
    ret,old_frame = cap.read()
    old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break


    mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)
    while (1):
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)


        good_new = p1[st==1]
        good_old = p0[st==1]


        for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
            a,b = new.ravel()
            c,d = old.ravel()
            mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
            frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
        img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

        cv2.imshow('frame',img)


        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff


        old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
        p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
```

Comment: are you using opencv2.4 ? (line/circle do not return anything in 2.4, so your mask and frame ge overwritten with None)

Comment: yeah that was it.. thanks :))

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
mask = cv2.line(...)
frame = cv2.circle(...)
```

But cv2.line and cv2.circle return None.

Comment: yeah that was the problem .. I was using opencv 3 and it worked perfectly, I had no idea that it would be a problem with opencv 2.4
thank you :)))

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask using cv2.inRange function or cv2.calcBackProject function and then try this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).